# How to know about MIDI controller via OTG latency on device?

Tags: hardware, usb-on-the-go

I have both these devices. I read somewhere that Android doesn't support good latency for MIDI devices as iOS do. But when I connect MIDI device to Sony Xperia M5, it has high latency. If I connect to Lenovo Tab 10, it's much better. I can even play normally on MIDI keyboard with Lenovo Tab 10. Both devices run Android 6.0. Is it possible to know if device has good latency or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So High Performance or Low Latency Audio on Android has been a work in progress for quite some time as seen on the [Android Developer Audio Latency page](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/audio/audio-latency).

Ideally the device will report supporting `android.hardware.audio.pro` feature flag indicating some level of compliance with the Android Compatibility Definition Document regarding 20ms round trip latency.

[Superpowered](https://superpowered.com/) is a company that makes an Audio SDK does provide [test app and chart of devices/OS versions & buffer sizes with their latencies](https://superpowered.com/latency). While I'm not sure of the model versions that you have, you can use the APK on the page to test your current devices and use the list to inform future purchasing decisions.

Comment: Thank you very much. My devices are Sony E5603 and Lenovo X103F. I didn't see my devices in that page. But where can I see if it has `android.hardware.audio.pro`? I recently ordered this phone (still waiting for it). But here I can't see anything about audio pro or audio latency.